# find and replace for setBackgroundImage with regular expression

Tags: ios, iphone, regex, xcode, nsregularexpression

Here is my objective. 
I want to search all `setBackgroundImage` call in my project and replace it with

```
[button setBackgroundColor:fixedColor];
```

problem is after setBackgroundImage: image name is different at different place. so i can not replace it in one go.

Is there any regular expression available for the same which i can use for find and replace ?

Comment: Could you provide a little ore information, please? Perhaps an example of an actual use of setBackgroundImage with an image name, and the replacement you would like to see?

Comment: currently there are multiple image set by setBackgroundImage:forState i want to find it and replace all with setbackgroundCOlor ... problem is string between Image:...forState is different so i want regex which can search every instance

Comment: Do you mean that you want to replace something like `[button setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];` to `[button.setBackgroundColor:fixedColor] ;`? or what would you like to replace it with?

Comment: @B.Dalton Yes .... exactly

Comment: Does this doe what you want ? regex: `"setBackgroundImage:.*forState:\w*"` (note that the \ may need to be escaped depending on how you use it: i.e. you may need to use \\ instead of \ ) , replacement text `"setBackgroundColor:fixedColor"`

Comment: It does exactly what i want ... Many thanks